# Timeshift v20 deletes my changes in Settings > Filters

Tags: kubuntu, timeshift

I try to explain [Timeshift](https://teejeetech.in/) v20.03 to exclude my download folder.

My Kubuntu using:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

I tried to add Exclusion here Settings > Filters:

change:

**Settings > Filters**:

```
⚈⚆ + /home/m/**
⚆⚈ - /root/***
⚆⚈ - /home/**
```

to:

```
⚈⚆ + /home/m/**
⚆⚈ - /root/***
⚆⚈ - /home/m/Downloads/***
⚆⚈ - /home/m/Downloads/**
```

then i pressed OK Button <kbd>OK</kbd>.

I looks created. Got no errors.

but if i open the **Settings > Filters** again my both new lines are not there. its looks like before.

Comment: maybe a bug ? https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues/496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this bug as well, even though Timeshift seems to be actively maintained they aren't resolving this. In addition, the default filters (viewable by clicking Summary on the Filters tab) are hardcoded so they can't be overridden without a code change.

If you just need to add filters or change the order assuming the default filters aren't a problem for you, you can get around this bug by modifying the `/etc/timeshift.json` file.

However, I found the default backup tool that ships with Ubuntu serves my purposes better - `Super + backup`. It allows you to include or exclude any folder as you see fit and can backup to cloud storage (as well as local of course).